# How to calculate bass in web audio api (javascript)

Tags: javascript, audio, fft, web-audio-api

I am attempting to determine the current bass of the sound coming from my microphone using web audio api (javascript). I am able to get the volume by creating an empty Uint8Array and using the analyser node to gather the frequency Bin count.

```
this.volume = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(this.volume);

var values = 0;
var length = this.volume.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  values += (this.volume[i]);
}
var volume = values / length;
```

And I am attempting to get the bass using the following logic

```
let bass = this.volume
let CalculateRMS = (arr) => Math.sqrt( 
    arr 
        .map( val => (val * val)) 
        .reduce((acum, val) => acum + val)/arr.length 
); 

let RMS = CalculateRMS(bass);
```

I am getting a value returned (eg 9.793971359974462), However I am unsure if this the correct way to determine the bass of incoming audio. Is this the correct way?

Comment: I would say bass indicates the lowest set of frequencies ... you are not defining this set

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about defining this "set" of frequencies? I am not sure I understand what you mean.